# Invoking dynamic Method without known Constructor?

Tags: java, reflection, dynamic

If I do this in Java to call a method name from a class dynamically, it works.

```
MainApp app = new MainApp();
Method meth = app.getClass().getMethod("myMethod", MyParameterType.class);
//call method
meth.invoke(app, new MyParameterType("hello"));
```

But this worked because I know the constructor in the invoke method. But if I were to pass the Method object as a parameter to some other classes, and I don't know who is the constructor, I cannot invoke the method any more. Even if I know, I may not want to create a different object to just make a call to the method. For eg:

```
//This is in the class call MainApp.java. 
//There is a method in MainApp.java that looks this way: myMethod(MyParameterType param);
MainApp app = new MainApp();
OtherClass myClass = new OtherClass();
Method meth = app.getClass().getMethod("myMethod", MyParameterType.class);
myClass.callMe(meth);

//Inside OtherClass.java
public void callMe(Method meth) {
    //call method
    meth.invoke(########, new MyParameterType("hello"));
}
```

In this case, what should I put for the ######## parameter? Within the context of OtherClass.java, the base constructor object wouldn't be known. And why would I need if since meth is already a Method type that I just call like a function?

Thanks

Comment: Hmmm... You seem to be missing the fundamental point that Java methods are invoked upon objects... you've extracted the method from the object, and passed it instead of the object? Why? Just pass the instance, and invoke the method upon it... it's a REALLY common pattern. I don't see the motivation for all this reflective voodoo.

Comment: If I pass it directly in, it will create a brand NEW object, which may not neccessary have the same information as the original object. This is my concern.

Comment: Huh? You pass an object, and the reciever "calls you back" using that object... so object must somehow be a NEW object. I suspect you're misunderstanding one (or more) of the fundaments of object-oriented programming... and I suspect that what you're really looking for is a dependency-injection framework. It would help to know what your motivation is. *Why* do you want a reflective solution in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's an instance method, you've got to have *an* instance to call the method on, just like anything else. How you get hold of that instance will depend on what you're trying to do; you could pass in a `Constructor`, or a reference to an existing object, or some interface which will create the instance when you ask it to... we can't really give you any advice on which approach is the most suitable without knowing what you're trying to do.

If it's a *static* method, you can pass `null` for the first argument.

Answer (score 1):

What it seems you are looking for or thinking about is the concept of `lambda functions``. Those can be called in isolation.

A Method type is not a standalone method, but more like a 'path' into an object. Compare this with a relative URL like `/subscribe.html`. Out of context this is pretty useless, but when bundled with a site like `www.example.com` it makes sense.

As such, Method can only be used in combination with an instance. *(edit: as John mentioned, unless it's a static method of course which do not need instances)*

Comment: I like that analogy of site and page.

Answer (score 0):

If you can safely invoke a method without providing an instance, it should be a static method, in which case any instance provided is ignored, you can give it `null`.

If you have to provide an instance of the object, there is no way around this.

If the developer who write the method has labelled it non-static incorrectly, I suggest you discuss with them why they did it.